# A producer-consumer code using semaphore compiling but not running

Tags: c, compilation, pthreads, semaphore, producer-consumer

i am in a very sticky situation as i am unable to figure out the problem with my producer-consumer problem using pthreads. the code compiles but when i run the code nothing happens and the expected output does not show. i believe there is a probelem in my producer and consumer threads with the if/else statement but i may be something else. the code is as shown below:

To compile it on command line:

```
gcc -pthread -lrt semaphore.c -o semaphore
```

Once you run the program it dosent display the correct output

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: you might want to check the return value from `pthread_create`.

Comment: The minimum would be to put some print statements in key places, and run it, so we can see where it went...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider some sample output to go with it; but I noticed that your producer and consumer threads start by:

```
int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
sleep(rNum);
```

Simply removing this from both threads made your program work.  On my edition of linux, RAND_MAX is 2^31, so these could cause an up to 21 second sleep in each thread.